# How to make a rightrightarrows

Tags: arrows

I want to make a `$ \rightrightarrows $` (basically two rigtharrows vertically aligned) in a latex file, I have tried to use some libraries, but I don't have a clue which one is the right one (I'm also failing totally about finding it about).
I have tried to include `ansmath`, `ansmath` + `tikz` + `arrows`.

Additional question, how should one go about when encountering "! Undefined control sequence." and googling the name of the sequence doesn't give results?

Comment: You can look up symbols in the [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive), or alternatively, try [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Note that it's `amsmath`, not `ansmath`. Your second question is a bit vague; can you be more specific about the help you need?

Comment: The specific case that I had in the second question was that I knew the name of the sequence (rightrightarrow), but I didn't knew which package to include. I asked the question, because when I encounter a similar case in the future I didn't have any lookup method. Symbols section from Detexify also give package name, so that is covered now. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the command/symbol `\rightrightarrows` exists in `amsfonts`.

`\usepackage{amssymb}` to gain access to it.

`texdoc amsfonts` for the `amsfonts` user's guide.

Comment: Just in case anybody wonders: `\rightrightarrows` looks like this: ⇉